# Kafka JDBC sink connector with Json Schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

i have a sink connector writing in postgreSQL with following configuration.

```
{
    "name": "connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresuser=user&password=123",
        "topics": "kafka-to-jsonb31",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "dialect.name":"PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
        "table.name.format":"sample_jsonb",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8090/json-schema.txt",
        "auto.create":"false",
        "auto.evolve":"false",
        "pk.mode":"none",
        "pk.fields":"none",
        "transforms": "timestamp",
"transforms.timestamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.timestamp.target.type": "Timestamp",
"transforms.timestamp.field":"timestamp",
"transforms.timestamp.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }
}
```

this works perfectly if i provide schema within the Kafka Message, but i would like to have a separate file containing schema definition and only the actual payload should be sent to the connector. for that purpose i tried

```
 "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8090/json-schema.txt",
```

but looks like connector is not able to pick up the schema and throws below exception

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

below is the message i want the connector to receive

```
    {
"data": "{\"name\":\"name11\",\"age\":26}",
        "timestamp":"2021-08-09 17:39:00"
        
}
```

and below is the content of schema file

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [{
            "field": "data",
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false
        }, {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`value.converter.schema.registry.url` should contain only the URL of the schema registry :
`"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8090/"`

The subject will be found thanks to the [Subject Name Strategy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#sr-schemas-subject-name-strategy), as long as your schema registry already holds the schema.

Also, you have to use this converter : `value.converter=io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter` instead of `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`. [This one allows you to use schema registry with json messages](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/connect.html#json-schema).

`JsonConverter` needs you to provide the schema inside the message (the problem you are currently facing). See [this article](https://www.confluent.fr/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas) to have some more details.

Comment: thank you for the answer, any idea how can i register my schema with schema registry? i believe i'll have to use kafka-schema-registry?

Comment: You can register your schema via [curl command](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/using.html#register-a-new-version-of-a-schema-under-the-subject-kafka-value)

Comment: it looks like schema registry is part of confluent not apache kafka? am i correct?

Comment: Yes, Schema Registry is not part of Kafka broker. In fact, you could have a Kafka cluster running without a Schema Registry. [Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html#sr-overview) says : _Schema Registry lives outside of and separately from your Kafka brokers._

Comment: i meant is this a part of Apache Kafka? because with default Apache Kafka implementation: in kafka/bin folder i don't see any .sh file through which i can run schema-registry. however in confluent documentation i'm seeing that schema-registry can be run through bin/schema-registry-start ./etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties. so i assume schema-registry is not a part of apache kafka but confluent platform.

Comment: @FaheemSultan That is correct, although Confluent Platform includes Apache Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

> works perfectly if i provide schema within the Kafka Message

I'm sure about "perfect"... If you want to use `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`, then you'd actually not be using the Schema Registry, so the url property isn't being used.

If you want to use a static schema file, that would need to be included as part of your producer code, not the sink connector

For example, in pseudo code

```
schema = read("schema.json")
payload = {"schema": schema, "payload" : some_data}
producer.send(topic, value=payload)
```

In the schema file itself, you don't need a top-level `schema` key

If you did want to use some HTTP endpoint referring to a schema file, you'd need to write your own converter or transform since the Confluent Schema Registry isn't "a file server" like you seem to be using it as

Comment: so if i include schema in the producer, it should work with org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter? or do i need to use io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter as Raphallal mentioned in above answer?

Comment: @FaheemSultan It'll work with the first, assuming you have `value.converter.schemas.enable=true`, as the error indicates ... `JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires ...` more details - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/